# How to solve this piece wise discontinuity problem?

Tags: continuity

The function is $f(x)=x²+cx+6$ if $x<1$;$f(x)=x²-x-c$ if $x\geq1$.
I approached the problem like this. 
For $f(x)$ is continuous if $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)=f(1)$

$\lim_{x\to1+} x²-x-c=-c=f(1)$.
Also $\lim_{x\to1-}x²+cx+6=c+7$. Then $-c=c+7$ and therefore $c=-7/2$.
Graphing I have realized that I'm wrong what am i missing or doing incorrectly?.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your calculation is correct, you likely graphed it incorrectly. I just graphed it, and it looks fine.

Comment: I just realized my mistake ignoring a negative sign. Good think is that I learned a little bit more about writing mathematical equations and symbols in LaTeX. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have $f(1)=-c$ and also
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=-c
$$
Moreover
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=c+7
$$
So continuity requires
$$
c+7=-c
$$
hence $c=-7/2$. So this is right.

[image]